# How to open program from command line in the background (below windows already opened)?

Tags: background, xterm

I have small python script that opens few dozens of instances of xterm and closes most of them after few seconds.

Using command like this:

```
for i in range (80)
    os.system("xterm -e echo example &")
```

allow xterm to be opened 80 times but windows are popping in front of the work space - so using any other program is impossible for minute or so.

Is there any way of opening those windows in the background?